# Combine split and align environment

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, split

The `split` environment allows you to give one number to two equations, as in

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a&=1+2+3+4\\ 
b&=5+6+7+8
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

which gives

[image]

Note that the equation numbre is nicely centered in the middle of the two equations.

The `align` environment allows you to put multiple equations ("tabs") in the same line, as in

```
\begin{align}
 a&=1+2+3 & b&=4+5+6\\
 c&=2+4+6 & d&=3+5+7
\end{align}
```

which gives

[image]

Is there a way to use the multi-tab functionality of `align` together with a single equation number like in `split`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the `aligned` environment:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
 a&=1+2+3 & b&=4+5+6\\
 c&=2+4+6 & d&=3+5+7
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

[image]
If you want to have control  on the gap between groups of alignments, you can use the `alignedat{n}` environment, where *n* is the number of groups, requiring *2n-1* ampersands.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
 a&=1+2+3 &\hspace{1in}b&=4+5+6\\
 c&=2+4+6 & d&=3+5+7
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

As pointed by egreg, the `tbtags` option doesn't work in that case, so that one has either to use the `[t]` or `[b]` option of the `aligned/alignedat` environments, or to use an `align/aligned` environment and the `\notag` command at the relevant places:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}[b]{2}
 a&=1+2+3 &\hspace{1in} b&=4+5+6\\
 c&=2+4+6 & d&=3+5+7
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\begin{alignat}{2}
 a&=1+2+3 &\hspace{1in} b&=4+5+6\notag\\
 c&=2+4+6 & d&=3+5+7
\end{alignat}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: Oh! yes.  I forgot this point. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: One loses the automatic feature of the `tbtags` option, so in this case the `aligned` or `alignedat` environment should receive the appropriate `[t]` or `[b]` optional argument.